# Search through adminhtml grid not working 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, adminhtml, debugging

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 Search through admin grids suddenly stopped working.
No js files with 404 status, no errors in js console. 
Script `productGridJsObject = new varienGrid(...` is present, as it should.

Only error is when anu button is clicked:

`(index):522 Uncaught ReferenceError: productGridJsObject is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):522)`

I thought it was defined, really.

How to debug it?